# Use a pandas dataframe created by function 1 in function 2?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, return

I have a function 1 which creates a pandas dataframe by importing data from excel.
Now I need to work with that data in a different function 2, but I dont manage to get the dataframe from function 1 back to the main code aswell as in function 2.

I cant publish the original code, but here is a simplified example of what it looks like

I got error: name 'parameter' is not defined

```
def function1()
    parameter = pd.read_excel("IDA_IDs.xlsx")
    return parameter

def function2(parameter)
    print(parameter)

function1()
function2(parameter)
```

Comment: `function2(function1())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is that you can define it as a global as well. If you want to act on the global data in your function/method, you should not pass it as a parameter.

```
def function1()
    global data
    data = pd.read_excel("IDA_IDs.xlsx")

def function2()
    print(data)

function1()
function2()
```

Comment: thanks, this was the missing piece for my project. It works now like I wanted

Comment: Appreciate it! If you could upvote the accepted answer as well, it might help others. Best of lucks!

Comment: upvote done, but it doesnt count, because I am a new member

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

```
parameter = function1()
function2(parameter)
```

or same code:

```
function2(function1())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I have tried but doesnt get to work for me.